# Setting height for a overflow-y doesn't seem to appear

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my page contents below the transparent header as demonstrated on my website. However, the overflow-y for the wrapper around the contents won't appear when setting the height of it to 100%. The height of the content is large enough for it to appear when set to auto. How do I make the height of the wrapper equal to the height of the page without including the height of the header so it scrolls?

My website: https://fortnitematcher.com

The wrapper:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="mainContainer" style="">
                <div class="containerTitle">Matchmaking for Fortnite with FortniteMatcher</div>
                gtgwgrtgr<br>gtgwgrtgr
            </div><br>
            <div class="mainContainer" style="float: left; width: 780px;">
                <div class="containerTitle">Matchmaking for Fortnite with FortniteMatcher</div>
                gtgwgrtgr<br>gtgwgrtgr
                <div class="containerTitle">Matchmaking for Fortnite with FortniteMatcher</div>
                gtgwgrtgr<br>gtgwgrtgr
                <div class="containerTitle">Matchmaking for Fortnite with FortniteMatcher</div>
                gtgwgrtgr<br>gtgwgrtgr
                <div class="containerTitle">Matchmaking for Fortnite with FortniteMatcher</div>
                gtgwgrtgr<br>gtgwgrtgr
                <div class="containerTitle">Matchmaking for Fortnite with FortniteMatcher</div>
                gtgwgrtgr<br>gtgwgrtgr
                <div class="containerTitle">Matchmaking for Fortnite with FortniteMatcher</div>
                gtgwgrtgr<br>gtgwgrtgr
            </div>
            <div class="mainContainer" style="float: right; width: 280px;">
                <div class="sideContainerTitle">Matchmaking for Fortnite with FortniteMatcher</div>
                gtgwgrtgr<br>gtgwgrtgr
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The style:

```
.wrapper {
        margin-top: 75px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        /*height: 90%;*/
    }
    .content {
        padding-top: 25px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        min-height: 1000px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        width: 1130px;
    }
    .mainContainer {
        padding: 15px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 82px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #000;
        color: grey;
        width: 1100px;
        min-height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try adding `.wrapper { height: calc(100vh - 75px) }`, would this be what you'd need?

Comment: Works! Thanks for the help. Im assuming the 100vh gets the full screen height and the 75px equates for the header?

Comment: May I ask why a percentage value doesn't work?

Comment: because percentage for heights depends of the cases and the parent DOM element, whereas the percentage of "width" depends of the screen width.

Comment: Yes, 100vh is basically "100% of the screen height". 50vh would be half the screen. `vw` also exists for screen width. As for Percentage heights in CSS they are a bit weird, 100% kinda only works if the parent has a height other than auto. And yes, the 75px is the height of the header (35px height + 20px padding-top + 20px padding-bottom)